# VPN into private network?

Tags: vpn, nat

I am trying to access a network in our office to allow access to a local server, this server is able to send out but is unable to be reached outside of the office network.

Would it be possible to bridge a vpn network or something similar? If so, how would it be achieved?

Comment: Have you considered simple ssh port forwards?

Comment: We do not have access to the layer above our router which is the final point before WAN access. It is rented office space so we are on a shared network (worth mentioning that this isn't against the network policy).

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know quite what you're trying to tell me. Do you mean you can't create a port forward in the router?

Comment: You could try something like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/)?

Comment: That looks like overkill to me

Comment: It works around firewalls which is what the OP was saying they were restricted by. Depends on exactly what they're attempting to accomplish. I agree it's a little overkill for simple access.

Comment: @RobbieMckennie That is indeed what I am trying to tell you. I am unable to change NAT settings because we do not have access to the router in control of that.

Comment: @JamieB This technique has nothing to do with the router, you can connect from the internal server to your remote server over ssh and forward tcp back through the encrypted tunnel to the machine behind the firewall.

Comment: @RobbieMckennie Does this allow both directions of data flow? We are trying to expose certain web services publicly (my networking experience is limited).

Comment: I'm not sure by what you mean by data flow in both directions but in a certain sense, yes. Although it would technically work, i would not recommend using it to provide web services in an enterprise environment. In fact, i cannot think of a satisfactory arrangement short of opening a port on the router. Have you considered off-site hosting?

Comment: It is a temporary solution to provide a POC to justify off-site hosting. If you you are able to provide a simple guide or link to a resource in an answer I could accept it?

Comment: I can, but i need to confirm you have a remote machine with an ssh server

Comment: We have a CentOS machine on a public network (we have control over) and a Windows machine on the inside network.

Comment: Which port/s do you need forwarded?

Comment: 8888 & RDP standard port

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about violating local security and network policy.

Comment: I don't think you have enough information to judge that

Comment: @MadHatter Please read the explanation, this isn't against our network policy.

Comment: I see that you put that in a comment, rather than in the question, but fair enough.  That said, this question was closed as "too broad", so I fear that your clarification isn't grounds for reopening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plink, you could use something like this:

```
plink.exe <options> -R *:8888:localhost:8888 -R *:3389:localhost:3389 username@host
```

Where `<options>` are things like compression, priv keys, and backgrounding the process. If you just run `plink.exe` on it's own you can see a list of these options.